# Custom Google map parameters Remove mini menu

Tags: html, google-maps

http://mtavares.geantduweb.ca/en/annonce?view=fiche&task=fiche.display&fiche_id=5

Ive looked all over the place... how to i turn off the
Map / Sat / Ter / Earth menu on the mini map... My user can click on To extend the map and get all them options. but there isn't any room for them in the small version...Anyone have any ideas?

Here is my link generator (for joomla 2.5 in PHP):

```
function getGoogleMapData($data='') {
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        $data = array();
        $data['addr']           =   $this->_data->addr;
        $data['ville']      =   $this->_data->city;
        $data['province']   =   $this->_data->province;
        $data['postal'] =   $this->_data->postal;
    }

    //Build the address into a string based on the data we have
    $gm = array();
    $gm['addr']  = '';
    $gm['addr'] .= ($data['addr']!='') ? $data['addr'] : '';
    $gm['addr'] .= (($gm['addr']!='') && ($data['city']!='')) ? ',' : '';
    $gm['addr'] .= ($data['city']!='') ? $data['city'] : '';
    $gm['addr'] .= (($gm['addr']!='') && ($data['province']!='')) ? ',' : '';
    $gm['addr'] .= ($data['province']!='') ? $data['province'] : '';
    $gm['addr'] .= (($gm['addr']!='') && ($data['postal']!='')) ? ',' : '';
    $gm['addr'] .= ($data['postal']!='') ? $data['postal'] : '';
    $gm['param'] = ($gm['addr']!='') ? urlencode($gm['addr']) : '';

    //Use new address string and make URL to google map and a SRC URL for inside iframe (embed)
    if ($gm['param']!='') {
        //Popup window : &amp;iwloc=A
        //&amp;sll=45.488370,-73.463742
        if (JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag()=='en-GB') {
            $lang='en';
        } else if (JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag()=='es-ES') {
            $lang='es';
        } else {
            $lang='fr';
        }

        $gm['embed']    = sprintf('https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=%s&amp;hl='.$lang.'&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=%s&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed', $gm['param'], $gm['param']);
        $gm['url']      = sprintf('https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=%s&amp;hl='.$lang.'&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=%s&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;source=embed', $gm['param'], $gm['param']);

        if (JFactory::getApplication()->getName()!='site') {
            //Remove adresse popup in iframe if back-end. window too small
            $gm['embed']    = str_replace('iwloc=A&amp;', 'iwloc=&amp;', $gm['embed']);
            $gm['url']      = str_replace('iwloc=A&amp;', 'iwloc=&amp;', $gm['url']);
        }
    }

    return $gm;
} //End of makeGoogleMap()
```

I've tried this link but it didn't help...
http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

This part removes the white popup... but how to prevent clicking the marker and it opening... id change the click so it opens the enlarged version or sumthing.

```
    if (JFactory::getApplication()->getName()!='site') {
        //Remove adresse popup in iframe if back-end. window too small
        $gm['embed']    = str_replace('iwloc=A&amp;', 'iwloc=&amp;', $gm['embed']);
        $gm['url']      = str_replace('iwloc=A&amp;', 'iwloc=&amp;', $gm['url']);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [google map small controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834188/google-map-small-controls) (if you are really using the Google Maps API v3 as your tag implies)

Comment: no my tags says Google-map... not google map API. my iframe map is just a link generated based on regular searches. im not using the API as it needs an API key... i may need to resort to this... but for the moment I don't see the need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess its not doable.

my work around... was to make the google map Bigger and put it inside of a smaller div centering it with negative margins and used overflow:hidden to hide the menus...

If i had more room i would leave the menu and google logos, but the space is soo small...

Kinda feel bad about hiding the google logo at the bottom... would of left it there... but its the only way that i found for the center marker to be centered in the box...